# How to provide my API for only some applications?

Tags: php, api

I'm building an API that I want to be private, I want to make sure that only the applications I want can read my data, I don't want anyone who can go to www.domain.com/api/getdata to read my data. How can this be done?

Comment: With a key for each accepted user:
www.example.com/api/getdata/?key=ret8hgubjoergnoerigh

Comment: A lot of larger APIs seem to be very fond of OAuth, there are libraries for most languages available if you want to pursue that path.

Comment: who the heck voted this as not constructive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do it is to give each client an api key and when an incoming request is received make sure the api key matches the client's host.

Or you could try [oauth](http://php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php)

Comment: and how can I get the client's host?

Comment: get the referrer with `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

Comment: but for file_get_contents() I can't check the referrer!!

Answer (score 1):

While you can use OAuth for this,

There is another way - you can use XML or JSON for your clients. They do some request and your script will return XML or JSON respond.

**About privacy**.
There's a common way to ensure that only your clients can access particular part of the script. This is a token. You can create this one per user then compare on each API request against array of tokens (or something like this)